# Is there a way to find out, with a command line, if a pypi package had installed also in /usr/local/bin?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I know, for example, that `python3 -m pip install -U mypy` will install `mypy` and `mypyc` in `/usr/local/bin`.

So, essentially, I like to know if there's a command line that could tell me, among all my `pip list` packages, which ones are doing something in `/usr/local/bin` other than just the `site-packages` folder.

Comment: have you tried `pip list -v`

Comment: just did, yet everything is shown in `...lib/python3.9/site-packages`

Comment: Maybe manually scan `/usr/local/bin`